# Performance comparison between LDAP servers

Tags: ldap, benchmark

Has anyone ever compared different LDAP servers? I am currently planning to upgrade ADAM to another server, and I'd like to know how do they perform.

Currently the options that I am researching are:

- Active Directory (LDS)
- OpenLDAP
- Red Hat Directory Server
- OpenDS
- OpenDJ

**edit: I am looking for any kind of measurement that has been done. Anything as basic as reads/writes per second. I am looking for any quantitative measures to support choosing any of the servers above for my upgrade.**

Comment: You missed eDirectory from Novell.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by ops/second?  Reads vs Writes?  With or without ACL evaluation?  Usually how each system handles ACL's greatly affects read results, since it needs to calc if you should be able to see the result or not.

Comment: LDAP servers are not compared by performance it usually boils down to compatibility(with clients), installation overhead, sclability(multi-master replication), integration(integrate with AD for kerb passwd) etc. Most of the LDAP servers have better performance beyond requirement. Setting up one server and thrashing with million queries is not realistic. It's like wanting to know the fastest car on planet and realizing that you won't be able to drive that fast. Pick something that fits your requirement!

Comment: @Prashanth Thanks, but you are not helping with your comment. All other parameters for comparison are available in their documentation. My question was not about the other factors. I am looking for the information that is not publicly available.

Comment: Actually, where I work LDAP performance is a big issue.
So this is still a valid question.

Comment: how big is the deployment ? Its pretty rare that ldap speed is a bottleneck ?